# Reason to use Postman for Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, rest, testing, django-rest-framework, postman

I'm used to test Django Rest Framework apps with the test tools available directly in Django and DRF. It's possible to setup a dummy client and expose all the REST methods. 
At the same time, I see many posts talking about Postman for API testing. I fail to see where the advantage would be.

Is there any reason for me, a single developer, to use Postman? Or perhaps there is only an advantage for shared projects?

Comment: But... without Postman - or some equivalent, eg sending requests via curl - you're not testing the API, are you?